# How to identify the removable singularity for this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

The function
$$
f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2-\pi^2/4}
$$
has two removable singularities at $z=\pm\pi/2$. I'm wondering is there a formal approach to determine the singularities are removable? Intuitively, I determined they're removable because at those points we have a $0/0$ form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just that they are of the form $0/0$, it's that both $\cos(z)$ and $z^2 - \pi^2/4$ have **simple** zeros at $\pm \pi/2$.  That is,
there are nonzero constants $a$ and $b$ such that $\cos(z) \sim a (z-p)$ and $z^2 - \pi^2/4 \sim b (z-p)$ as $z \to p$ (where $p = \pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$),
so that $\cos(z)/(z^2-\pi/4) \to a/b$ as $z \to p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this a theorem ($h(x)=f(z)/g(z)$ has simple zeros at $z_0$ if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ both have simple zeros at $z_0$)?

Comment: You mean $h(z) = f(z)/g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ both have simple zeros at $z_0$ (or more generally, if they have zeros of the same order there).

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!